# cordova plugin is not ready

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a plugin to get information from DB, then display the information on the page. But I can't get it work when the page is loaded. It only works in a event handler.

I have tried to bootstrap my app in 'deviceready' event. Still don't work.

Please help me! Thanks!

The index.html file:

```
<body ng-controller='loginCtl'> {{company}}
<div class="list list-inset " style="margin-top:20px;">
<button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
</div> 
</body>
```

The app.js file:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    angular.bootstrap(body,['starter']);
    //company =myplugin.getCompany(); -- doesn't work here
}

angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
//......
});

angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('loginCtl', function($scope) {
    //$scope.company  = myplugin.getCompany(); --- doesn't work at here
    $scope.login=function(){
      company =myplugin.getCompany(); //work at here
      $scope.company = company;
    };            
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's pretty typical of plugins like these:  the software MIGHT NOT be ready "when the page loads," and it is unpredictable how long it might take for that *"Okay, I'm ready now"* event to arrive.  Therefore, you might have to *(for instance)* initially create the page with a bunch of stuff hidden, and reveal them only when you receive the ready-signal.  (And, by the way, be sure to test this sort of stuff on the SLOWEST, OLDEST, MOST MEMORY-STARVED piece of equipment you can dredge-up at a local dime-store, 'cuz **that's** what your real user's gonna have in his pocket.)

Comment: @oldbird have you included Cordova.js file in your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comments. I finally resolved this issue by copying device plugin. My plugin.js is not correct.

This is my original code, which only works in an event handler.

```
var myplugin = {
    getCompany:function() {
        exec(function(info)
         {company=info.company;},
         null, "Myplugin", "getLoginInfo", []);
        return company;
    }
};
module.exports = myplugin;
```

This is copied from cordova-plugin-device, which works in "deviceready" event:

```
channel.createSticky('onCordovaMyReady');
// Tell cordova channel to wait on the CordovaInfoReady event
channel.waitForInitialization('onCordovaMyReady');

function Myplugin() {
    this.company = 'none';
    var me = this;
    channel.onCordovaReady.subscribe(function() {
       me.getLoginInfo(function(info) {
               me.company = info.company;
               channel.onCordovaMyReady.fire();
           },
           function(e) {                                             
               utils.alert("[ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: " + e);
           });
    });
}


Myplugin.prototype.getLoginInfo = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
           exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Myplugin", "getLoginInfo", []);
};

module.exports = new Myplugin();
});
```